error in uploading file using a slack bot?
I was following a youtube tutorial and he used a third party github repo to make code easiervfor uploading file since it's wrapper function that does the api calls for us . problem is function's parameter got updated and i also updated it accordingly but still getting "Error uploading file: method_deprecated"
channel id and bot token are correct.
here is the updated file structure from that repo
type FileUploadParameters struct {
    File            string
    Content         string
    Reader          io.Reader
    Filetype        string
    Filename        string
    Title           string
    InitialComment  string
    Channels        []string
    ThreadTimestamp string
}

I updated it my code
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/slack-go/slack"
)

func main() {
    os.Setenv("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN", "xoxb-7723840493030-7759198065952-6gEE05CZv1muXgCDl9tLEUrg")
    os.Setenv("CHANNEL_ID", "C07MDHHLCHK")

    api := slack.New(os.Getenv("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))

    channelID := os.Getenv("CHANNEL_ID")
    filePath := "resume_.pdf"


    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening file: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()


    params := slack.FileUploadParameters{
        Channels: []string{channelID},
        File:     filePath,
    }


    uploadedFile, err := api.UploadFile(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error uploading file: %s\n", err)
        return
    }


    fmt.Printf("Name: %s, URL: %s\n", uploadedFile.Name, uploadedFile.URL)
}

Also oauth permissions given are:-
channel:read
chat:write
file:read
file:write
im:read
im:write
mpim:history
remote_files:read
remote:files:write
remote_files:share


The API Docs state "Newly created apps will be unable to use files.upload beginning May 8, 2024". More info in this issue, you will need to update the code to use a different API call.

Use the FileUploadV2 function instead to perform the upload the correct way as stated in the comments for the FileUpload func on the library:
// Deprecated: Use [Client.UploadFileV2] instead. This will stop functioning on March 11, 2025.
// For more details, see: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload#markdown

